# How to print for loop with 2 lists?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have 2 lists:

```
filtered_items_list = [src1, scr2, scr3]
filtered_items_url_list = [url1, url2, url3]
```

I want to print this as

```
src1, url1
src2, url2
src3, url3
```

If I try:

```
>>> for src, url in filtered_items_list, filtered_items_url_list:
    print src, url
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

If I try this:

```
>>> for src in filtered_items_list:
        for url in filtered_items_url_list:
            print """"src: %s; url: %s""" % (src, url)
```

I get this:

```
"src: src1; url: url1
"src: src1; url: url2
"src: src1; url: url3
"src: scr2; url: url1
"src: scr2; url: url2
"src: scr2; url: url3
"src: scr3; url: url1
"src: scr3; url: url2
"src: scr3; url: url3
>>>
```

Can you suggest a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `zip()`:

```
for src, url in zip(filtered_items_list, filtered_items_url_list):
    print src, url
```

Comment: [izip](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) tends to b a better option, because it avoids unnecessarily copying the lists. Note that they both cut off at the end of the shortest list. If you want to go to the longest use `izip_longest()`, and it will fill in a None (or some other default you specify) for the remaining ones.

Comment: @chmullig: zip does not copy the lists, it just returns a list. Not that this matters the slightest with 3 elements.

Comment: And for completeness: in Python 3, `zip` behaves like `izip`, and the latter is gone.